# I want to see all the labels on the X-axis of my graph in Chart.js, but only a few of the labels are coming.

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there any way where I can get to see all the labels? All the points are being plotted and the tooltips show the label and the value correctly, but all the labels on the X-axis are not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You need to set **`autoSkip`** property to **`false`** for x-axis ticks, to show all the labels.

```
options: {
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            autoSkip: false
         }
      }]
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: may be he/she did not accept but +1 from my side for this. :D i have seen your answer on about every chartjs post :) cheers

Comment: @ℊααnd It worked ! Thank you so much !! This was of great help.